# Apple ID for iPhone X in Myanmar

Tags: iphone, ios

I ordered an iPhone X from the US. Now I am using it in Myanmar, but I cannot sign in to Apple ID. It asks for an address, phone number and Zip Code in the United States. However I do not have those. What do I need to do to set this up?

Comment: What language and country/region did you select when when you first set up your phone?

Answer (score 1):

I like to go to the apple.com page where you buy a phone and tap the OS section. At the bottom of it, there is a small print section making note that not all features are available everywhere. Currently this link is:

- https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/

Sadly for you and residents of Myanmar - there is not one feature offered in that country. You may have to use your presence in another country to establish an account to use some of the features of the stores and OS that are only available in certain countries.

Start with the list above and perhaps pick one or two things you really need to do and see if you have any ties to those places to have some legitimacy for establishing an account without fabricating all the details or going to the expense of establishing an address in the US.